# Sintax error in PHP invoking an array inside a column

Tags: php, arrays

Can anyone tell me where is the syntax error of the following code:

```
echo "<td bgcolor=.$cores[i].></td>";
```

`$cores` is an array of colors codes:

```
$cores = array("#FF0000","#FFBF00","#FFFF00","#04B404","#58FAF4","#0101DF","#8A0886");
```

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me where is the syntax error of the following code:"* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php  and view HTML source.

Comment: PHP is also not recursively embeddable/executable. `.` inside your string is pointless - those are literal `.`, not concatenation operators.

Comment: shouldn't it be $cores[$i] ? Is 'i' a (undefined so treated as string) constant?

Comment: error reporting should be throwing you an undefined constant i notice.

Comment: the erros it complains is this: Notice: Undefined index: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ficha4_4\ficha4_2.php on line 22

Comment: Damien Pirsy is right: it's missing $i. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<td bgcolor={$cores[$i]}></td>";
```

Comment: Or `echo '<td bgcolor="'.$cores[i].'"></td>';`

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I don't like to use that syntax, it hurts my eyes :)

Comment: @DamienPirsy well spotted :)

Comment: *this this* - explaining where code may be failing, is crucial for anyone wanting to learn ;-)

Comment: It's not working neither of these solutions.

Comment: @TiagoDavid Paste the full error message

Comment: It's missing a $ before i in the array parameter: should be: echo '<td bgcolor="'.$cores[$i].'"></td>';   Thank you.

Comment: The problem now is that it's putting the different colors in rows instead of columns.